# How to interface ros controller and orocos?

Tags: ros, ros-controllers, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do i use orocos rtt with ros controller for hard real time controll?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290984/how-to-interface-ros-controller-and-orocos?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a basic example of this some time ago, might be useful to get started: https://github.com/skohlbr/rtt_ros_control_example

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-05-16**:
great, but why r the read and write functions empty? it would be more helpful if they were also present. what single board computer were u using to run ros and how did u connect sensors and motors? through gpio, ethercat or serial port?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-05-16**:
so sir, basically the only part needed to interfaced with orocos is the hardware interface part right?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2018-05-17**:
The read and write functions depend on the hardware you use and how it can be interfaced (perhaps via a driver/library provided by the vendor).